# How to fill nested list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a nested list and I need his to fill the values ​​returned from the function. Is something like a two-dimensional matrix, where the number of rows is equal to the length of a list, and the number of columns of the length of another list. The question is how to call index to the elements of a nested list?

```
List<int> wordids;
List<int> hiddenids;
List<List<int>> inputWeights;

foreach (var wordid in wordids)
{
    foreach (var hiddeid in hiddenids)
    {
         inputWeights[wordid][hiddenid] = GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid);
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4):

You will need add lists to inputWeights as you go:

Using an outer `foreach` outer and an inner `for` loop:

```
var inputWeights = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (int wordid in wordids)
{
    var currentRow = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenids.Count; ++i)
        currentRow.Add(GetStrength(wordid, hiddenids[i]));

    inputWeights.Add(currentRow);
}
```

Using two `foreach` loops (this is my preferred solution, but opinions may differ!):

```
var inputWeights = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (int wordid in wordids)
{
    var currentRow = new List<int>();

    foreach (int hiddenid in hiddenids)
        currentRow.Add(GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid));

    inputWeights.Add(currentRow);
}
```

Or using Linq instead of the inner loop:

```
foreach (int wordid in wordids)
{
    var currentRow = new List<int>();
    currentRow.AddRange(hiddenids.Select(hiddenid => GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid)));
    inputWeights.Add(currentRow);
}
```

Or even using Linq for the entire thing (it's becoming unintelligible now ;):

```
var inputWeights = wordids.Select(
    wordid => new List<int>(hiddenids.Select(hiddenid => GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid)))
).ToList();
```

And just to be *really* complete, here's a solution using Linq Query Syntax (and yes, I spent too much time messing around with this, but I couldn't stop once I'd started... ;)

```
var inputWeights = (from wordid in wordids
                    select (from hiddenid in hiddenids
                            select GetStrength(wordid, hiddenid)).ToList()).ToList();
```

That's all assuming you actually want (#wordids * #hiddenids) in the results! Is that really true?

For example, if you have 10 wordids and 5 hiddenids, the output will have a total of 50 items.

Comment: Matthew Watson, thank you. But inputWeights[] initially empty.

Comment: @HelioGracie Sorry I misread the original code - is my updated code better? It fills in `inputWeights` as it goes.

Comment: Your first example will not work because you don't want to reference `inputWeights[i]` inside the inner loop, you want to reference the list you just added to it.  All the other examples are correct however.

Comment: @juharr Thanks - I messed up my editing quite spectacularly. Should be fixed now, I hope!

Answer (score 1):

use two dimensional array or jagged array

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];
jaggedArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 };
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22 };

a=jaggedArray[0][1];  //a=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case you shouldn't use `foreach`, but rather a usual `for`-loop, like

```
List<int> wordids;
List<int> hiddenids;
List<List<int>> inputWeights;

wordids = new List<int>();
hiddenids = new List<int>();
inputWeights = new List<List<int>>();

//add values to your List-objects

foreach (int i = 0; i < wordids.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (int j = 0; j < hiddenids.Length; j++)
    {
         inputWeights[i][j] = GetStrength(wordids[i], hiddenids[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't initialize `inputWeights` or any of it's internal lists.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! But it could have been for visualization only, too!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<int>> inputWeights=new List<List<int>>();

 for (var i = 1; wordids.Count > i; ++i)
 {
   for (var h = 1; hiddenids.Count > h; ++h)
   {
    inputWeights[i-1][h-1] = GetStrength(wordids[i-1], hiddenids[h-1]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't initialize any of the internal lists inside of `inputWeights` and really should be using `Add` for a list.